# first iteration of php loop not being wrapped

Tags: php, css, sql

In the following set of files, the first result isn't being wrapped in the 'result' div, and so isn't being styled properly.  All the subsequent results are being wrapped properly.  Help?

**form.php**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script language ="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(event) {
            var form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize()
                }).done(function(returned_data) {
                    document.getElementById('scriptsearch_results_div').innerHTML = returned_data;
                }).fail(function() {
                    alert("The search has failed.  Please alert the webmaster.");
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
...
<div id="formcontainer">
    <form id="scriptsearch_form" action="scripts_post.php" method="post">
        // form fields
        <p> <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submitbutton" id="mainsubmitbutton"> </p>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="scriptsearch_results_div">
    <p>Search for scripts using the options at left.</p>
</div>
```

**scripts_post.php:**

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("server", "user", "password", "dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlQuery);
if (empty($result)) { 
    echo 'No results found'; 
    return;
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    include 'single_result.php';
}
echo "<div class='results_end'><p>End of list</p></div>";
mysqli_close($connection);
```

**single_result.php:**

```
<div class='result'>
    <div class='result_left'>
        <div class='result_photo'><img src=<?php echo "'" . $row['PhotoLink'] . "'" ?> height='200' width='200' class='script_photo'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='results_right'>
        <div class='result_title'><?php echo $row['Title'] ?></div>
        <div class='result_summary'><?php echo $row['Summary'] ?></div>
        <div class='result_description'><?php echo $row['Description'] ?></div>
        <div class='result_preview'><a href =<?php echo "'" . $row['PreviewLink'] . "'" ?> target='_blank'>view preview</a></div>         
        <div class='result_detail'>Type: <?php echo $row['Type'] ?></div>   
        <div class='result_detail'>Biblical Characters Portrayed: <?php echo $row['BiblicalCharacters'] ?></div>
        <div class='result_detail'>Topics: <?php echo $row['Topics'] ?></div>
        <div class='result_price'>Cost: $<?php echo $row['Price'] ?></div>
        <div class='result_purchase'><a href =<?php echo "'" . $row['DownloadLink'] . "'" ?> target='_blank'><img src='http://image.payloadz.com/images/btn-addtocart-b.png' border='0'></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't echo an include in all cases, echo include is wrong

Comment: Sidenote: Your `mysqli_close($connection);` is in the wrong place, so you're closing your DB connection prematurely.

Comment: @CodeBird - I'm still learning.  How do I do that properly?

Comment: try moving this mysqli_close($connection); under echo "<div class='results_end'><p>End of list</p></div>"; as @Fred-ii- said and remove your echo include, just keep include

Comment: Thanks, @CodeBird.  Glad for the quality increase.  Still need to fix my initial container problem.

Comment: trying to figure it out, nothing's coming to my mind, are you sure the problem is coming from the first result isn't being wrapped in the 'result' div. Like do you see what the php is returning in the ajax and you see div class='result' isn't there?

Comment: @CodeBird, I double-checked the source and the 'scriptsearch_results_div' contains: a 'result_left' div and a 'results_right' div and then a bunch of 'result' divs.

Comment: is it something we can't see online?

Comment: @CodeBird, I'm working that angle now; was working locally.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47792/discussion-between-codebird-and-eleventhousand-db)